# IIS 7.5 don't let to use stream cipher!

Tags: iis, internet-explorer

Internet Information Services 7.5 in Windows 7 don't let me to use stream cipher. When I change the local group policy to force the use of stream cipher or GCM mode, which works like stream cipher, IIS page can not be loaded by any browser I try, even when I restrict the client browser cipher suite to stream cipher.

I have the same problem with internet explorer 11 when I restrict its cipher suite to stream cipher, it can not connect to Apache server even though Apache first suggestion is a cipher using GCM.

i spend a lot of time to resolve this problem but i can't! please help me

Comment: Off topic here - also, please do not cross post!